# Combine rows from self-referenced table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

For an Excel export I have to add two columns to each item with all their "has-reference-to" and "is-referenced-from" items.

[Here is my SQL Fiddle with my tables and my results.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6fba/1)

**My tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Item (ItemId INT, Title NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO Item VALUES(1, 'Title 1')
INSERT INTO Item VALUES(2, 'Title 2')
INSERT INTO Item VALUES(3, 'Title 3')
INSERT INTO Item VALUES(4, 'Title 4')
INSERT INTO Item VALUES(5, 'Title 5')

CREATE TABLE ItemReference (ReferenceId INT, FromItemId INT, ToItemId INT)
INSERT INTO ItemReference VALUES(1, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO ItemReference VALUES(2, 1, 3)
INSERT INTO ItemReference VALUES(3, 4, 5)
INSERT INTO ItemReference VALUES(4, 5, 1)
```

Both `FromItemId` and `ToItemId` contain an `ItemId` from table `Item`.

**Expected output**

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title   | Has reference to | Is referenced from |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 1 | Title 2, Title 3 | Title 5            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 2 |                  | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 3 |                  | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 4 | Title 5          |                    |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 5 | Title 1          | Title 4            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
```

**My query**

```
SELECT item.Title,
    ISNULL([Has reference to], '') [Has reference to],
    ISNULL([Is referenced from], '') [Is referenced from]
FROM Item item
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT i.Title + ', '
    FROM ItemReference ref
    INNER JOIN Item i ON ref.FromItemId = i.ItemId
    WHERE ref.FromItemId = item.ItemId
    ORDER BY ref.ToItemId DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
) OURT ([Has reference to])
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT i.Title + ', '
    FROM ItemReference ref
    INNER JOIN Item i ON ref.ToItemId = i.ItemId
    WHERE ref.ToItemId = item.ItemId
    ORDER BY ref.FromItemId DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
) OURF ([Is referenced from])
```

**Current output**

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title   | Has reference to | Is referenced from |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 1 | Title 1, Title 1 | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 2 |                  | Title 2            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 3 |                  | Title 3            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 4 | Title 4          |                    |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 5 | Title 5          | Title 5            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
```

As you can see, the number of item references matches my expected results but I can't get the correct title of the references. Could anyone help me get the correct titles?

Comment: Wouldn't that be ref.Title (not i.Title) in both outer applys? BTW your fiddle didn't load for me (might be spcific to my connection).

Comment: SQL Fiddle has been slow/not working lately for me too. Couldn't load it either. Perhaps copy/paste the create/insert statements directly.

Comment: @CetinBasoz The table `ItemReference` doesn't have a column `Title`...

Comment: I added the create statements for the tables to my question. I can't open the fiddle through the link either (only with refreshing the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my ignorance that ref doesn't have item column, without data sample I couldn't see the tree I think :)

```
SELECT item.Title,
    ISNULL([Has reference to], '') [Has reference to],
    ISNULL([Is referenced from], '') [Is referenced from]
FROM @Item item
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT i.Title + ', '
    FROM @ItemReference ref
    INNER JOIN @Item i ON ref.ToItemId = i.ItemId
    WHERE ref.FromItemId = item.ItemId
    ORDER BY ref.ToItemId DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
) OURT ([Has reference to])
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT i.Title + ', '
    FROM @ItemReference ref
    INNER JOIN @Item i ON ref.FromItemId = i.ItemId
    WHERE ref.ToItemId = item.ItemId
    ORDER BY ref.FromItemId DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
) OURF ([Is referenced from]);
```

Links should be ref.To and ref.From (were ref.From and ref.To).

EDIT: BTW, because of order by it is Title 3, Title 2. I am not sure if it is what you want.

Comment: Oh, so it was just a mistake with my joins... Thank you :)